# Bijection from 2^X x Y and (2^X)^Y and describe the elements of each

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let **2** = {0,1} and X,Y be sets.

(i) Describe the elements of **2**<sup>X x Y</sup> and (**2**<sup>X</sup>)<sup>Y</sup>

The first is a function from X x Y to **2** so the elements would have the form ((x,y),0) or and ((x,y),1) and the second is a function from Y to the function from X to **2** so the elements would take the form (y,(x,0)) and          .(y,(x,1)).

Is this how I would describe the elements?

(ii) Find a bijective function from **2**<sup>X x Y</sup> and (**2**<sup>X</sup>)<sup>Y</sup>

I know what a bijection is but I'm not sure how to go about finding one and proving it

Comment: The second case is wrong: elements of $(2^X)^Y$ take the form $(y,f)$, where $f\in 2^X$. Your $(x,0)$ and $(x,1)$ are not elements of $2^X$; they are elements of elements of $2^X$.

Answer (score 1):

For each function $f:X\times Y\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ define the 
function $g:Y\rightarrow (X\rightarrow\{0,1\})$ by parametrization $g(y) = f(.,y)$. 
Then $g(y)(x) =f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $(y,(x, 1/2 \pm 1/2)) \mapsto (x, y, 1/2 \pm 1/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach.

Identify $2^{X\times Y}$ with $\wp(X\times Y)$ and identify $\left(2^X\right)^Y$ with $\{f\mid f\text{ is a function }Y\to\wp(X)\}$.

---

There is a one-to-one relation between subsets of $X\times Y$ and functions $Y\to\wp(X)$.

If $A\subseteq X\times Y$ then $A$ determines the function $f_A:Y\to\wp(X)$ that is prescribed by:$$y\mapsto\{x\in X\mid\langle x,y\rangle\in A\}$$

If conversely $f:Y\to\wp(X)$ denotes a function then $f$ determines the set:$$A_f:=\{\langle x,y\rangle\mid y\in X\wedge x\in f(y)\}$$

It is not difficult to prove that $f_{A_f}=f$ and $A_{f_A}=A$ (proving that the relation is one to one).